# Jquery - How to prepend image before span text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write code in Jquery to find each image inside ul element and prepend him before element span in my html. Thank you very much.

JQuery:

```
if($('#mod-links li img').length > 0){
    $('#mod-link li img').each(function(){
       alert('testing'); // just for test alert doesn't work in my case.
       $(this).prependTo($(this).parent().closest('span));
    });
}
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="mod-links">
  <li style="padding-bottom: 10px;">
    <img alt="test" src="borgwarner80.jpg " /><!-- this is image i need move before text in span -->
    <a class="ui-link" href="?do=article">
      <b>BorgWarner Chooses ATS ...eness (OEE) Deployments</b>
    </a>
    <br>
    <span class="small">OEE is way to measure m...ality and productivity.</span><!-- this is  is place where i need to prepend my image -->
    <br class="clear">
    </li>
    <li style="padding-bottom: 10px;"></li><!-- same structure with different image and text -->
</ul>
```

Comment: Try with `$(this).parent().find('span')`

Comment: you missed single quotes around `span`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to select correct id `#mod-links`

```
if($('#mod-links li img').length > 0){
    $('#mod-links li img').each(function(){
       //     ^^^^
       alert('testing'); // just for test alert doesn't work in my case.
       $(this).prependTo($(this).parent().find('span'));
       //                                ^^.find()  ^^quote
    });
}
```

You could also simplify your code like this

```
$('#mod-links span.small').prepend(function(){
   return $(this).closest('li').find('img');
});
```

Comment: No need to retrieve parent, use siblings('span') instead ! check out my answer ..

Answer (score 0):

USe like this,

```
$('#mod-link li img').each(function () {
     $(this).parent().find("span").before(this);

 });
```

**Edit**
Like @Anton said, you also have a typo in the id selector, change `#mod-link` to `#mod-links`

```
$('#mod-links li img').each(function () {
     $(this).parent().find("span").before(this);

 });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can shorten your code using **[.insertBefore()](http://api.jquery.com/insertBefore/)**:

```
$('#mod-links img').each(function () {
    $(this).insertBefore($(this).siblings('.small'));
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4kQsT/1/)**

Comment: I think you answered to quickly `:p`.. what if there are multiple li elements ?

Comment: There are more then one img and span.small on my page. I mean there are several li with same structure. I think each and this is better in my case.

Answer (score 0):

move it before it's span sibling !

```
$('#mod-links li img').each(function(){
    $(this).siblings('span').before(this);
});
```